# Erro de sintaxe ao criar tabela no PostgreSQL utilizando Hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, postgresql

```
    @Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String sex;
    private int age;
    private Date birthday;
    private Date registerdate;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "eventlike_user", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_user"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_eventlike"))
    private Collection<Eventlike> eventlikes;
    @OneToMany
    private Collection<Event> events;

   //getters and setters
```

Recebo o seguinte erro na criação das tabelas:

> ERROR: HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table User (id int8 not null,
>   birthday timestamp, email varchar(255), login varchar(255), name
>   varchar(255), password varchar(255), registerdate timestamp, sex
>   varchar(255), primary key (id)) nov 12, 2014 10:55:33 AM
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute ERROR: ERRO: erro de
>   sintaxe em ou próximo a "User"   Posição: 14

Não sei o que está fazendo com que essa tabela não seja criada porém o que me chama atenção é esse tipo `int8` do `id`.

Comment: Não sei sobre o `int8`, mas fiquei intrigado com o ` ERRO: erro de sintaxe em ou próximo a "User" Posição: 14`. Você sabe do que se trata isso?

Comment: Não manjo mto de java, quando você têm caracteres acentuados ou letras maiusculas em nome campos/tabelas no postgres é obrigatório colocar aspas duplas no nome. Sugiro que você coloque a anotação do nome da classe/tabela manuante em caixa baixa ou o nome escapado com aspas duplas. Algo mais ou menos assim: `@table="user"` ou `@table="\"User\""`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse erro acontece porque caracteres acentuados, letras maiusculas e [palavaras reservadas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) devem obrigatóriamente ser escapados com aspas dupas `"`. No seu caso `user` é uma palavra reservada. Conforme esse [resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3611916/1342547) sua anotação deve ficar assim:

Para JPA 1.0

```
@Entity
@Table(name="`User`")
public class User {
    ...
}
```

JPA 2.0

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"User\"")
public class User {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O  PostgreSQL tem como convenção usar caracteres minúsculos para representar identificadores, ou seja, nomes dos objetos (schemas, tabelas, views, functions, procedures). É uma boa prática seguir isso.

Quando declaramos objetos com letras maiúsculas, temos que usar aspas. Por exemplo: `create table "User"`.

Até onde já pesquisei, o Hibernate não trata essas diferenças de forma transparente. Talvez até tenha algum parâmetro.

Você pode tentar adicionar a anotação `@Table` na sua classe especificando o nome em minúsculas. Exemplo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User { 
    ...
}
```

Além dessa alteração, verifique se a tabela já existe no banco e, em caso afirmativo, normalize o nome dela para minúscula. Faça isso para todas as tabelas.

Comment: É isso mesmo! Obrigado